# Annotating a method with @Transactional causes "No unique bean of type is defined: expected single bean but found 0"

Tags: java, spring

Annotating a method in the implementing class with `@Transactional` throws this exception.

```
// Interface
public interface JobManager {

    public void process(CommandLine parameters);
}

// Implementing class
public class UserJobManager implements JobManager{

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void process(CommandLine line) {
        // Stuff here
    }
}
```

Spring configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <bean id="benchmarkManager" class="com.test.userjobmanager.UserJobManager"/>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" order="10"/>

    <bean id="transactionManager" 
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">

         <property name="dataSource" ref="readDataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- other beans here -->
</beans>
```

When i'm accessing the bean like:

```
JobManager jobManager = ac.getBean(UserJobManager.class);
```

I've got the following stacktrace:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   unique bean of type [com.test.userjobmanager.UserJobManager] is
>   defined: expected single bean but found 0:  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:269)
>   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1083)

If I remove the `@Transactional`, it works fine.
I am not sure what the problem is here.

Comment: @AliDehghani Added transaction manager config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you're using a proxy technology that creates a synthetic class. That is to say, the real class of your transactional bean may no longer be `UserJobManager`. I'd recommend accessing the bean by name instead:

```
JobManager jobManager = ac.getBean("benchmarkManager", JobManager.class)
```

Comment: Worked !. So does that mean that the synthetic class that is created, is also an interface type ?

Comment: Yes... the synthetic proxy class implements the interfaces of the class being proxied.